# How to modify aws EBS volume attribute

Tags: python

Am writing code to set EBS volume to delete on instance termination

I have this code:

```
v.modify_attribute('blockDeviceMapping', {'/dev/sda1': False})
```

I have this code:

```
v.modify_attribute('blockDeviceMapping', {'/dev/sda1': False})
```

but am getting errors

These are my errors:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the ModifyVolumeAttribute operation: No attributes specified.
```